# Restoring default MySQL state, like transactions but global.

Tags: mysql, testing, transactions, rollback

I'm trying to put together a testing environment for an API based service. Ideally, I'd like to have a default database each test begins with.

What makes this interesting is that I'd like to trigger writes, reads, updates all via the API, which will be hitting the database like any other normal day. I'm just trying to determine the best way of rolling back these changes. I'm aware of transactions, but those seem to be connection dependent and I can't guarantee each operation will use the same connection due to the nature of a web application.

My first-ditch attempt at this would likely involve importing the entire database each time. I know this will work, but it will likely be slow.

Transactions seem like they could work, but I am relatively new to using them in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are not what you are looking for if you actually need to verify that test data has been written to a database.  You will never have visible access to a transaction that has not been committed.

If you are doing this for unit testing of the code and you do not actually need to verify the data written in the database, then you should create a database mock to use instead of a real database.  If you need to actually validate database writes, and if you know each test will only alter a few tables in the database, one thing you might want to do is have the SQL available to drop/create/populate the tables of concern such that you can do this before each test execution rather than having to deal with a full import of a mysqldump.

One tester I worked with before took a similar approach in having template tables in his testing database and made copies of each applicable table (using `CREATE TABLE test_table LIKE template_table` and `INSERT INTO test_table SELECT * FROM template_table`) before each test run and then just dropped the test tables in the tear down stage for each test.

Comment: I'm trying to have as light of a touch on the actual code as possible, unfortunately, so changes to table names, etc would be undesirable. 

You have inspired me to try copying data *out* of each table, and then restoring it upon test completion. Maybe I could even simply have multiple schemas and drop it in that way. My hope is that it will be relatively faster than a complete re-load.

Comment: @omgz0r In any case, you are going to need to execute some set of SQL commands on test set up and tear down. Personally, I like having a full table drop, table create, table insert SQL command to execute within the test itself, as then you can check in the actual test table structure into you code repository and developers can modify the SQL as needed in the test suite when they make any schema changes to the tested tables.  I don't prefer as much the idea of copying a template table and using INSERT ... SELECT * queries, as the test could break if the data is changed in the database.